# Random walk on a segment with infinite time

Tags: infinity, random-walk

Given a point particle on a segment $L$ of length $1$, $(L=[0,1])$, assume the particle moving randomly in such a way: $p_{(k+1)}=p_k+\delta_k$ where $p_{k+1}$ is the position on the segment at time $t_{k+1}$ and $\delta_k$ a random number $\delta_k\in\mathbb{R},-1\lt\delta_k\lt1$. If $p_k+\delta_k\lt 0,p_{k+1}=|p_k+\delta_k|$ and if $p_k+\delta_k\gt1,p_{k+1}=p_k+\delta_k-1$ (reflecting walls), given infinite time, can we prove the particle will touch every point in the segment? 
If the set of all the time intervals is uncountable, I suppose the answer could be 'yes'. Is it a good answer? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "If the set of all the time intervals is uncountable"? The time steps are labelled by an integer $k$ and are thus countable. What are the "time intervals"?

Comment: @joriki: yes. So the answer is 'not' because $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, yes.